# How to fix errors which occured while extracting docker image layer?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, docker

I have configured docker to store all files on other filesystem.

This is docker configuration file (/etc/docker/daemon.json):

```
{
    "data-root": "/media/mint/MountDir/docker",
    "storage-driver": "vfs"
}
```

When I try to pull docker image I receive the following error when finishing extracting first layer.

```
5492f66d2700: Extracting [==================================================>]  54.92MB/54.92MB
e7c6a42bcdd9: Download complete 
failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: open /var/lib/dpkg/info/gcc-10-base:amd64.list: invalid argument
```

However it worked fine without "data-root" entry. The requested file: /var/lib/dpkg/info/gcc-10-base:amd64.list exists on main filesystem.
How do I fix this?

---

```
cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/gcc-10-base:amd64.list 
/. 
/usr 
/usr/share 
/usr/share/doc 
/usr/share/doc/gcc-10-base 
/usr/share/doc/gcc-10-base/README.Debian.amd64.gz 
/usr/share/doc/gcc-10-base/TODO.Debian 
/usr/share/doc/gcc-10-base/changelog.Debian.gz 
/usr/share/doc/gcc-10-base/copyright
```

Comment: Try finding a related */dpkg* package, one way is these: `$ apt-file find /var/lib/dpkg/info/gcc-10-base:amd64.list`
`$ apt-file find gcc-10-base:amd64.list`
`$ apt-file find amd64.list`                           ... and apt-file might be something you need to install first...

Comment: "... extracting docker image layer" - is that a single package or a set of related ones? Do you have a pointer to related instructions, which you were following?

Comment: apt-file find /var/lib/dpkg/info/gcc-10-base:amd64.list returned: 'Finding relevant cache files to search ...E: The cache is empty. You need to run "apt-file update" first.' After apt-file update the following commands: $ apt-file find /var/lib/dpkg/info/gcc-10-base:amd64.list $ apt-file find gcc-10-base:amd64.list $ apt-file find amd64.list returned nothing. The problem have not been solved. I tried docker pull jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11

Comment: Does that file exist? Does it contain something that seems relevant if it is there? Do `touch /var/lib/dpkg/info/gcc-10-base:amd64.list` if isn't already there.

Comment: file exists,  the following command:

cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/gcc-10-base:amd64.list
-
prints:
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/gcc-10-base
/usr/share/doc/gcc-10-base/README.Debian.amd64.gz
/usr/share/doc/gcc-10-base/TODO.Debian
/usr/share/doc/gcc-10-base/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/gcc-10-base/copyright

Comment: Please provide answers in the way that I indicated in the posting: `<hr> ....` - Now, I'm not acquainted with docker, I believe that is required to get any further here,

Comment: Are you running out of disk space?

Comment: Yes that is why I am setting new docker path where I have available space.