# Error when trying to build Docker container on external SSD (Ubuntu 22.04.2)

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm trying to build a docker image on an external SSD since my system drive is too small.
I've installed docker as recommended on the system and and after stopping docker in the `daemon.json` file set `root-data` parameter to the path on my external SSD (`"data-root": "/media/path/to/drive/docker"`). However, when trying to build the Hello-world container I get the following Error:

```
 docker build -t hello-world .
[+] Building 10.1s (5/80)                                                                                           docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 6.51kB                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                                               2.1s
 => CANCELED [internal] load build context                                                                                    7.9s
 => => transferring context: 929.52MB                                                                                         7.9s
 => ERROR [ 1/78] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:33a5cc25d22c45900796a1aca487ad7a7cb09f09ea00b779e3b2026b4fc2fab  7.9s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:33a5cc25d22c45900796a1aca487ad7a7cb09f09ea00b779e3b2026b4fc2faba         0.0s
 => => sha256:33a5cc25d22c45900796a1aca487ad7a7cb09f09ea00b779e3b2026b4fc2faba 1.13kB / 1.13kB                                0.0s
 => => sha256:3246518d9735254519e1b2ff35f95686e4a5011c90c85344c1f38df7bae9dd37 424B / 424B                                    0.0s
 => => sha256:6df89402372646d400cf092016c28066391a26f5d46c00b1153e75003465484d 2.30kB / 2.30kB                                0.0s
 => => sha256:edaedc954fb53f42a7754a6e2d1b57f091bc9b11063bc445c2e325ea448f8f68 27.51MB / 27.51MB                              5.2s
 => => extracting sha256:edaedc954fb53f42a7754a6e2d1b57f091bc9b11063bc445c2e325ea448f8f68                                     2.0s
------
 > [ 1/78] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:33a5cc25d22c45900796a1aca487ad7a7cb09f09ea00b779e3b2026b4fc2faba:
------
Dockerfile:2
--------------------
   1 |     #Download base image ubuntu
   2 | >>> FROM ubuntu:20.04
   3 |     
   4 |     ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to register layer: open /var/lib/dpkg/info/gcc-10-base:amd64.list: invalid argument
```

The `gcc-10-base:amd64.list` file exists on my system drive and when building `hello-world` without the `root-data` set in `daemon.json`, it builds and runs normally.
I've found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1712948/how-to-fix-errors-which-occured-while-extracting-docker-image-layer) issue and followed the suggestions, however the `apt-file` command returns nothing.
Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?
Thank you very much!

```
docker --version
Docker version 24.0.5, build ced0996
```